Ticks Disappear From LogLinearPLots
Can someone explain why the ticks on my plots disappear?
Initially they're present
Plot1 = Show[Table[LogLinearPlot[ {i*x^4} , {x, 10^-4, 10^-2}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic}, ImageSize -> Full], {i, 1, 5}]];
Plot2 = Show[Table[LogLinearPlot[ {i*x^4} , {x, 10^-4, 10^-1}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic}, ImageSize -> Full], {i, 1, 5}]];
Plot3 = Show[Table[LogLinearPlot[ {i*x^4} , {x, 10^-4, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic}, ImageSize -> Full], {i, 1, 5}]];

GraphicsRow[{Plot1, Plot2, Plot3}, ImageSize -> Full]


You do not need this option value PlotRange -> {Automatic}.

This fixes it for me:
plot1 = Show[
   Table[LogLinearPlot[{i*x^4}, {x, 10^-4, 10^-2}, 
     PlotHighlighting -> None], {i, 1, 5}]];
plot2 = Show[
   Table[LogLinearPlot[{i*x^4}, {x, 10^-4, 10^-1}, 
     PlotHighlighting -> None], {i, 1, 5}]];
plot3 = Show[
   Table[LogLinearPlot[{i*x^4}, {x, 10^-4, 1}, 
     PlotHighlighting -> None], {i, 1, 5}]];

GraphicsRow[{plot1, plot2, plot3}, ImageSize -> Full]


Seems to be another of those buggy things from the dynamic highlighting. The crashing tick labels happens in plot1 and plot2 (at normal size), too.

Weirdly, this doesn't solve the issue for me unfortunately.

@NavStoke Then set ImagePadding on each plot manually. Or try Row instead of GraphicsRow. I guess some system differences explain the above not working. For me, without PlotHighlighting -> None, I'd get the ticks initially and they would disappear when the mouse moved over the graphics.

Use Row rather than GraphicsRow
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

plts = Show[
     Table[
      LogLinearPlot[{i*x^4}, {x, 10^-4, 10^#},
       PlotRange -> Automatic,
       ImageSize -> 225],
      {i, 1, 5}]] & /@ {-2, -1, 0};
Row[plts]


To get individual colors for the curves, put the Table inside of the plot and use Evaluate.
plts = LogLinearPlot[
    Evaluate@Table[{i*x^4}, {i, 1, 5}],
    {x, 10^-4, 10^#},
    PlotRange -> Automatic,
    ImageSize -> 225] & /@
  {-2, -1, 0}; Row[plts, ImageSize -> Full]



@Moo - The small ImageSize causes the tick labels to overlap. Using fewer tick labels; or increasing the ImageSize and using Column rather than Row can resolve this.
